# Specifying type of inline object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm using `TypeScript` and I have the following scenario.

Let's say I have a base type and some derived types, something like this:

```
export interface Base {
  id: string;
}

export interface A extends Base {
  propA: string;
}

export interface B extends Base {
  propB: string;
}
```

And let's say I also have an array of the base type:

```
let items: Base[];
```

Now, here's my problem: I want to initialize that array with some objects, and I though I could just do this:

```
items = [
  {id: "1", propA: "foo"},
  {id: "2", propB: "bar"}
];
```

However, this doesn't work, I get an error from the compiler saying that:

> TS2322: Type '{ id: string; propA: string; }' is not assignable to
> type 'Base'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'propA' does not exist in type 'Base'.

But the objects I declared are indeed instances of `Base`, and in fact if I do something like:

```
const objA: A = {id: "1", propA: "foo"};
items.push(objA);
```

the compiler doesn't complain.

So, is it possible to do this inline object declaration, or am I forced to declare all objects separately and manually pushing them onto the array?

Comment: You're trying to circumvent [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks); note that you're not using your `A` and `B` interfaces at all, so the warning is that nothing in your code will remember those extra properties.  Either actually make values of type `A` and `B`, or use the various approaches the documentation suggests for circumventing the check.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMjEQW).  Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either

```js
items = [
    { id: "1", propA: "foo" } as A,
    { id: "2", propB: "bar" } as B
];
```

or

```
let items: Array<A | B>;
```

Comment: Ok, solution 1 works, for some reason I hadn't thought about casting (solution 2 not really applicable in my situation, because the types here are mapping corresponding types in a C# backend, and C# doesn't have the concept of union types unfortunately)